# Use wix to perform function of REGSVR32

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm new to wix and trying make an installer for a few dlls.  One of the tasks that has been done manually in the past is to use REGSVR32 to register the com objects.

I assume that RegisterClassInfo in wix will perform this function, but I've been uanable to find example code that shows the correct syntax.  I'd appreciate it if someone would point me to a good example or post it here as an answer.

Comment: same question / answered with additional details by [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463256/cannot-register-dll-using-wix?rq=1][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463256/cannot-register-dll-using-wix?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using wix v3.5 from the question's tag.

Basically, use the harvest tool (heat.exe).

The online documentation for it is here: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm

The wix download also includes offline documentation in WiX.chm.

A tutorial for it is here: 
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/components-of-a-different-color

Comment: Thanks @Rami. You are correct, this is for WIX 3.5. I ran the command line `C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin>heat file "c:\repository\bin\mytest.dll" -out c:\time\mytest.wxs` It resulted in a large wxs with many classes, interfaces, and registry values withing the fragment. Is all of this required in my final wxs?  Is this what regedit32 does?

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer. Yes it is, Heat does the same as regsvr32, but redirectes the registry calls to write the wxs file. (regedit32 is not used here.)