# Wix Toolkit: Heat balking about DLL's

Tags: .net, wix, wix3, heat, wix3.11

I'm just beginning to mess with Wix, and upon using heat.exe, it complained about 4 (and only 4) dlls I am referencing. About 30 others it was fine with.

1) I've got no idea as to what is causing this. Most SO posts about this sort of error are related to assemblies in the GAC, and heat being picky about path arguments. I don't think either of these apply. I can't imagine that a dependency wouldn't be here, but like I said, I'm relatively new at this.

2) Would statically linking these libraries into my application fix this problem? It certainly would make for a less messy of an install directory. If so, what would be the drawback?

> heat.exe : warning HEAT5151 : Could not harvest data from a file that
>   was expected to be an assembly: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyApp\MyAppControlPanel\bin\release\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.
>   If this file is not an assembly you can ignore this warning.
>   Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> heat.exe : warning HEAT5151 : Could not harvest data from a file that
>   was expected to be an assembly: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyApp\MyAppControlPanel\bin\release\System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll.
>   If this file is not an assembly you can ignore this warning.
>   Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reactive.Core,
>   Version=3.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> heat.exe : warning HEAT5151 : Could not harvest data from a file that
>   was expected to be an assembly: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyApp\MyAppControlPanel\bin\release\System.Web.Http.dll.
>   If this file is not an assembly you can ignore this warning.
>   Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> heat.exe : warning HEAT5151 : Could not harvest data from a file that
>   was expected to be an assembly: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyApp\MyAppControlPanel\bin\release\System.Web.Http.Owin.dll.
>   If this file is not an assembly you can ignore this warning.
>   Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What are the flags you are using? (heat flags)

Comment: At the moment, I've just cut and paste from some examples trying to make it work, and then get it done properly. Here's the build event -- 

call "$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" directory -dr TARGETDIR -cg ProductComponents -gg -g1 -sf -srd "$(ProjectDir)server.wxs"
-var var.MyAppControlPanelDir -out "$(SolutionDir)Setup\MyApp.wxs"

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463256/cannot-register-dll-using-wix

Although there are a few WIX bugs that describe a similar issue and they are still open: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/3337 , https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4108